# What is the purpose of SharePoint 2013 Site Content Type - "JavaScript Display Template"?

Tags: javascript, content-type, 2013, sharepoint-online

Under SharePoint 2013 Site Content Type - **JavaScript Display Template Content Type** is present, what is the purpose of the content type and how we use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out the purpose of the JavaScript Display Template Content Type, it is used to represent the JSLink files that we need to upload in the master page gallery which in turn is being used to apply display template @ list view, form and fields.

Comment: [JS Link for SharePoint 2013 Web Parts–A Quick Functional Primer](http://www.idubbs.com/blog/2012/js-link-for-sharepoint-2013-web-partsa-quick-functional-primer/) is the blog from where I got the answer.